# Nokia PC Suite hangs at installing required drivers and doesn't connect to phone

Tags: windows, drivers, nokia-pc-suite

I am unable to connect my Nokia 2690 to my PC via data cable using Nokia PC Suite under Windows XP SP3 Pro 32 bit.

Every time I connect my mobile using the data cable, the Nokia App shows a window where it says it's "Installing the required drivers. Please wait".

But even after several hours my phone never conects to my PC and the screen remains there idle. I checked in he task manager, Nokia PC Suite didn't go unresponsive.

Comment: Which USB mode did you select?

Comment: @Tog: PC suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this latest release of the [Nokia PC Suite](http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/downloads/) – this will surely solve your problem.